Association Problem in UML Class Diagram in papyrus- Eclipse for a model driven framework
I am working on a model driven engineering project and working with UML diagram in papyrus. Now, while creating association between certain classes,I am facing some problems.
In this diagram, there is an association between City class and ResidentialBuilding class. Now, my target was to make the association composite for the point going into City class by changing the aggregation type as composite on the other end, (ResidentialBuilding class end). And, I want to disable the navigable option for the City class which I did. SO, you see there is no arrow. Now, I want to make a reference of ResidentialBuilding class into the City class so that the attributes "residentialBuildings" is added to the City class. Now, I found a tutorial where they use UML Designer in eclipse. In UML Designer, there is an option in properties view "Owned" which can be diasbled. Papyrus doesnt offer anything like this. In the  second image, you can see what I am trying to achieve:  UML Designer offer a Owned option for each of an association which can be disabled or enabled. If anyone has the working idea of how association works in Papyrus UML project, it will be very helpful. Thanks. I have tried to find many solutions but not working.
I have tried changing the aggregation type at each end, and the Owner type. In papyrus, the Owner type only includes (Classifier/Association).
